# Is there a way to dynamically call functions by their name in c++

Tags: c++, function, c++14

I have a list of functions named as so, `void F1()`, `void F2()`.....

I ask the user to input a number and it will call the corresponding function.
So if they input `5` it will call `F5()`.

Rather than having one really long switch statement, I am wondering is there a way to do this by appending the users input to the function call.
Something like the below code

```
std::cout << "Please enter the number of the function you wish to call " << std::endl;

std::cin >> choice;

functionToCall = "F" + choice;
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6887471/2785528.

Comment: Technically it can be possible by using the dynamic linker. For example on the Linux platform using `dlsym`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9af85973cd1b7d45

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.
C++ doesn’t have this kind of reflection.

You can always create a structure which maps strings to function pointers, but you will have to initialize this structure yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> Rather than having one really long switch statement, I am wondering is there a way to do this by appending the users input to the function call.

No.

Not so simple.

The best I can imagine is the use of a `std::vector` of `std::function`s (or also function pointers) so you can write something as

```
vfunc[0] = &F0;
vfunc[1] = &F1;
// ...

auto functionToCall = vfunc[choice]; // or better vfunc.at(choice);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

typedef double(*pfunc)(double);
std::map<std::string, pfunc> functionMap_;


functionMap_["acos"] = acos;
functionMap_["cos"] = cos;
functionMap_["asin"] = asin;
functionMap_["sin"] = sin;
functionMap_["atan"] = atan;
functionMap_["tan"] = tan;
```

to have functions with more arguments you would need maps with other function pointers

```
typedef double(*p2func)(double, double);
typedef void(RPNCalculator::*spfunc)(void);
```

and so on